# Can adhoc distribution build be given by 2 developers?

Tags: iphone, build, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

We IPhone team are 3.Each has developer certificate and can debug from devices. But only one account has the access to build for Adhoc distribution. 
          So, Can we have 3 distribution profiles for all three. So any one can build Adhoc distribution with there profiles.(Not by exporting one account to all). If yes, can U please provide the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You guys need ONE common account at Apple's devleoper portal. (you may have more but one you need to share)
That is the one which owns the app id of your app. 
All three of you shold have team accounts within that one developer account. The first one, administrator per default, will invite the others.

Each of you will then go though the signature certification process. (starting with issuing a CSR from your macs) 
In addition to the usual process the administrator has to approve the individual's certificates if I'm not much mistaken. However, Apples developer provisioning portal will guide you through.

Then you need to include all the signature certificates into the distribution profile (just by clicking check boxes), re-issue and download the profile.
Each of you loads that profile into his xcode's organizer and each signes his code with his onw credentials.

Sounds complicated. In fact it is not much more complicated than the whole nasty process as such. And there is no need to export one's private keys and import them into the other's macs.

Comment: Thank You Klecker. We did the export of the profile in earlier days. Now will give it a try with this.